# sshfs metrics.sock: bind: operation not permitted

Tags: permissions, sshfs

I have my local computer and a vps server. I want to run an experiment where I run docker on the vps but the container that I build will be on another machine (I'm **not** looking to add a volume to a docker container)

I can ssh in to the vps and then sshfs to mount an external drive of my local computer onto my vps

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 123.456.78.9 -j ACCEPT // allow my vps on my local computer

ssh root@myvps.com -i mykey // ssh to my vps

sshfs -o allow_root,default_permissions root@011.23.58.13:/mnt/d1/ /mnt/d1/ -o IdentityFile=/root/mykey.pub // mount my local drive on my server
```

Still on my vps I run docker using my drive

```
dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker1.sock -p /var/run/docker1.pid --ip-masq=true --bridge=br1 --data-root=/mnt/d1/docker-data --exec-root=/mnt/d1/docker-exec --debug
INFO[2023-10-27T15:25:13.397535535Z] Starting up                                  
WARN[2023-10-27T15:25:13.397782724Z] Running experimental build                   
DEBU[2023-10-27T15:25:14.846130491Z] Listener created for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker1.sock) 
INFO[2023-10-27T15:25:14.847085018Z] detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf 
DEBU[2023-10-27T15:25:16.938257472Z] Golang's threads limit set to 2700           
DEBU[2023-10-27T15:25:19.670716238Z] Cleaning up old mountid : start.             
failed to start daemon: error setting up metrics plugin listener: listen unix /mnt/d1/docker-exec/metrics.sock: bind: operation not permitted
```

And I'm not sure why root is being denied to bind to the metrics.sock when I can see that it successfully created the root docker folders and the docker socket? Could it be something like Apparmor or the way I'm mounting?

I see on my local computer

```
root        7475  0.0  0.0   2792  1048 ?        Ss   16:24   0:00 fusermount3 -o rw,nosuid,nodev,fsname=portal,auto_unmount,subtype=portal -- /run/user/0/doc
```

What is saying operation not permitted?